# Finding the standard deviation of numbers, not sure what I am doing wrong in solving the problem?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

A police officer uses a radar gun to determine the speed of five vehicles traveling on the highway. The speed of those vehicles are as follows.

65, 55, 60, 66, 69

Find the standard deviation round to three decimal places.
I got the answer: 4.940

Not sure where the mistake is.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Could you include your work on the problem?

Comment: Be aware that there are two related but different concepts of standard deviation.  In one, it is used in the case that the data given is the full and complete definitive set of data possible, $\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{\sum (x-\overline{x})^2}{n}}$.  In the other, it is used in statistics in the case that the data is merely a random collection of data that is likely incomplete or possibly inaccurate, $\sigma_* = \sqrt{\frac{\sum(x-\overline{x})^2}{n\color{red}{-1}}}$

Comment: I wrote it on paper. It's using the generic std.dev formula std.dev = sqrt{ sigma i=1 to n (y_i - y-bar)^2 / (n-1) } I just took every number given and subtracted off the average, then I added up all the results and squared them, then divided by (n-1)

Comment: I expect that the question intends you to use the second one above, the *sample* standard deviation.  You divided by $5$ instead of dividing by $4$ in your calculations., i.e. you forgot to do $n-1$ instead of $n$ (*that or you counted the number of data points incorrectly*)

Comment: @JMoravitz I see. So in this case it sounds like it was complete because that is the entire population desired.

Comment: There are two possible questions we might want answered... "what is the standard deviation of the speed **of the cars tested**"  and "what is an *estimate* of the standard deviation of the speed **of all cars** (*even those we didn't test*)".  If we wanted to answer the first question, we would divide by $n$ (*in this case $5$*) in the calculations.  If we wanted to answer the second question, we would divide by $n-1$ (*in this case $4$*) in the calculations.  Your calculations giving an answer of about $4.940$ were as though you divided by $5$ when you probably should have divided by $4$.

Comment: Actually I think this might be a sample therefore it would be 5.523?

Comment: Just as a check:In R statistical software `x=c(65, 55, 60, 66, 69); sd(x)` returns 5.522681, which rounds as you say. This procedure uses 4 in the denominator, before taking the square root. (The _sample_ SD, not the _population_ SD.) If the source of this problem is a statistics book, I would say the sample SD is required. Clearly the five cars are described as a sample. (Hard to imagine a venue where only five cars exist and they need radar guns.) If population SD were required, I think there would be an instruction such as 'Treat these five vehicles as a population."

Answer (score 1):

**Comments on the denominator of the sample variance.**

The usual (but not only) definition of the sample variance is $S^2 = 
\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2.$ The popularity of this
definition probably arises from several theoretical considerations:

(1) $S^2$ is an unbiased estimator of the population variance $\sigma^2$
for most of the distributions used as population models, including
the normal distribution. That is $E(S^2) = \sigma^2.$

(2) In the common case where the population is normally distributed, the distribution of $S^2$ is closely related to the distribution
$\mathsf{Chisq}(n-1)$ [the chi-squared distribution with $n-1$ degrees
of freedom]. In particular, 
$$\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n-1).$$
This makes it easy to make a 95% confidence interval for $\sigma^2$ of
the form $\left(\frac{(n-1)S^2}{U},\,\frac{(n-1)S^2}{L}\right),$
where $L$ and $U$ cut 2.5% of the probability from the lower and
upper tails of the distribution $\mathsf{Chisq}(n-1),$ respectively. 
The same chi-squared distribution is used in conjunction with $S^2$
to test hypotheses about the population variance $\sigma^2.$

(3) In some applications it is convenient to use the sample standard
deviation $S$ (perhaps mainly because the units of $S$ are the same
as the units of the data). While $S$ is *not* an unbiased estimator
of the population standard deviation $\sigma,$ (that is, $E(S) \ne \sigma)$
the difference between $E(S)$ and $\sigma$ is not large for normal data
and gets smaller as the sample size $n$ increases. In many applications
the difference between $E(S)$ and $\sigma$ is simply ignored.

---

However, a few responsible authors suggest using the estimator
$V = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2.$ One argument for
this is that students don't need to fuss over the difference in
definitions between sample and population means. Another is that,
even though $V$ is slightly biased, it makes up for that by having
a slightly smaller variance.

More technically, the 'mean squared
error' of an estimator $T$ of a parameter $\tau$ is defined
as

$$MSE(T) = E[(T - \tau)^2] = Var(T) + B^2(T),$$
where $B^2 = [E(T) - \tau]^2,$ the square of the 'bias'.

For normal data $V$ has smaller MSE than does $S^2.$
Furthermore, the estimator 
$V^\prime = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2$
has a slightly smaller MSE than either $V$ or $S^2.$
While I know of nobody who is proposing to use $V^\prime$
as an estimator of $\sigma^2,$ I suppose a case could be made.

Even though it would not be correct to insist that $S^2$ is **the** correct
estimator of $\sigma^2,$ it seems to be established practice
to use $S^2.$ All estimators have advantages and disadvantages,
and established habit die hard, so I don't suppose we will see
a massive campaign to use another estimator anytime soon.

---

Suppose the experiment is to sample $n=5$ values from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100,\,\sigma=15).$ Then $\frac{4S^2}{225} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(4),$
so one can show that $E(S^2)=225$ and $Var(S^2)=MSE(S^2)=25,312.$
Similarly, $\frac{5V}{225} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(4),$ so that
$E(V) = 180,\,B(V) = -45,$ $Var(V)=16,200,$ $B(V)^2 = 2025,$ and $MSE(V) = 18,225.$

Notice that $S^2$ is unbiased, but has $MSE(S^2)=25,312 > MSE(V) = 18,225.$

The histograms below are based on a million realizations of $S^2$ (top) and $V.$
Means are indicated by vertical red lines. Superimposed curves are appropriately scaled densities of $\mathsf{Chisq}(4).$

[image]